# How to change the JSDoc Tutorial title

Tags: jsdoc

The jsdoc is really light without explanations. Can you please tell me how to change the name of the Tutorial section and have many sections according this file?

> tutorials/file1.md
>   tutorials/file2.md

I tried many things with a JSON file but nothing.

I would like the first title as: "Getting Started" in place of tutorials name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use .json extension instead of .js, and have it in the same folder with your .md file and have the same file name:

> tutorials/file1.md
>
> tutorials/file1.json

and likewise for your second file. Then you can try:

```
{
    "title": "Getting Started"
}
```

Comment: I do not want change the title of the file but change the "TUTORIALS" title. And if possible have multiple sections of tutorials, like "tutorials 1", "tutorials 2" and so on.